# How to calculate marginal effects of estimations of the GJRM function / package

Tags: r

I want to estimate (the marginal effects of) a recursive bivariate model in R as theoretically elucidated in Chapter 17.5.5 of the 7th Edition of Econometric Analysis of William Greene.

The setting can be shown by the following two equation system:

Y<sub>2</sub> = (Zα<sub>1</sub> + Xα<sub>2</sub> + v<sub>2</sub>) > 0

Y<sub>1</sub> = (Y<sub>2</sub>  β<sub>1</sub> + X  β<sub>2</sub> + u<sub>1</sub>) > 0

where Y1 and Y2 are the dependent binary variables, u1 and v2 the error terms of the latent variable form equations (multinominal normal distributed with means of zero), X describes a vector of exogenous covariates and Z describes a vector of valid instruments.

In Stata you can easily estimate this setting with the `biprobit` command. To get the marginal effects or to be more precise the Average Partial Effect (APE) one can use the standard `margins` command afterwards, e.g. `margins, dydx(Y2) pred(pmarg1)`

I know that I can use the `gjrm` function of the `GJRM` package in R to estimate the coefficients of the equation system above but I don't know how to get the corresponding marginal effects. Thus, I'm searching for a command to get the marginal effects. Unfortunately, the `margins` command in R does not seem to work / to be applicable after calling the `gjrm` function.

I had a look the description of the `GJRM` package and searched via Google. In the `GJRM` package the `PE` function may see appropriate at first glance. However, I think it is not an option since I'm not trying to do any "posterior simulation" and I have no idea what to specify as `idx` argument.

The following replicates my problem:

```
library("MASS")
library("margins")
require(GJRM)

N <- 10000
emeans <- c(0, 0)
ecovar <- matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,4),2,2)
e <- mvrnorm(n=N,emeans,ecovar)
u1 <- e[,1]
v2 <- e[,2]
X1 <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)
Z1 <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)


Y2_star <- 0.5 + 0.5 * X1 - 0.5 * Z1 + (v2 / sd(v2))
Y2 <- Y2_star > 0
Y1_star <- 1 + X1 - Y2 + (u1 / sd(u1))
Y1 <- Y1_star > 0

df <- data.frame(Y1,Y2,X1,Z1,u1,v2) 

reduced.eq <- Y2 ~ X1 + Z1
structural.eq <- Y1 ~ X1 + Y2
f.list <- list(reduced.eq, structural.eq)
mr <- c("probit", "probit")

bvp <- gjrm(f.list, data=df, Model="B", margins=mr)
summary(bvp)
```